# Need Inputs for Database Structure in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1.My query is regarding Firebase database structure for the below requirement and how to normalize the data.

I will have 0.5M records of members with classified functions under team categories, identified across multiple states -> regions -> zones.

2.Next, when a new member fills the form, the region tab should auto-populate based on the state chosen. So is the case of zones.

As a newbie to Firebase, I have planned to create States key_id and key_ids by push method for regions as well. Will this help in addressing most of operational queries on members with functions across state / regions / zones.

3.Will normalizing the data based on districts / members help.
I plan to duplicate the state, region & team category attributes in Members data to have efficient structure and reduced query time on vast no# of records.

Comment: You may have a look at this official Firebase video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o

Comment: This question is way to broad and we don't know what *classified functions* means. Also *normalizing* data is generally the opposite of what makes Firebase (queries) work well. See this video from @davideast [Denormalizing is Normal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA&feature=youtu.be).It sounds like you want to be able to drill down through states->regions->zones when a user taps each in the UI which should be fairly straightforward but we need more info.  If you can clarify the question (a lot) we may be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: Hi Vadim / Jay, thank you for the suggestions and recommendations given here. I was able to plan to complete the database structuring part.